# Is it possible to reference an output buffer at specific depth in PHP?

Tags: php

We can get ob level. We can get length of current ob stack. But can we reference ob stack at level *n*? I would really benefit of getting length of the buffer at specific depth.

Suppose an example:

```
$length = array();

ob_start();
echo "1";
$length[] = ob_get_length(); // length of current stack (depth 1) is 1
ob_end_clean(); 


ob_start();
echo "11";
ob_start();
echo "2";
$length[] = ob_get_length(); // length of current stack (depth 2) is 1
ob_end_clean();
ob_end_clean();

ob_start();
echo "111";
ob_start();
echo "22";
ob_start();
echo "3";
$length[] = ob_get_length(); // length of current stack (depth 3) is 1
ob_end_clean();
ob_end_clean();
ob_end_clean();

print_r($length);
```

Output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
)
```

The length of each most deepest stack is 1. This is as expected.

My app has recursive output generation and some of output stacks have to know the length of parent system-generated stack. I cannot rely on using `ob_get_length()` right before opening a new stack simply because other people could wrap the generator in their own ob stack. And that will break the app.

Are there any options? Thanks.

## EDIT:

To illustrate what I need to get:

```
ob_start();
echo "111"; // <-- this is the stack of interest
ob_start();
echo "22";
ob_start();
echo "3";
$length[] = ob_get_length(); // length of current stack (depth 3) is 1
$top_stack_len = get_length_of_ob_stack(1); // expected length here should be 3 (strlen("111") == 3)
ob_end_clean();
ob_end_clean();
echo "some more chars to change length of stack 1";
ob_end_clean();

echo $top_stack_len; // I'm expecting to see 3 here.
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Are you trying to get length of parent output buffer? (in third case '2')? will ob_get_status(true) help?

Comment: No, not the parent. But stack on 1st level, from 3rd. The goal is to avoid parent-bound calls.

Comment: So in short you want a function that will return '2' in second and '3' in third example?

Comment: Yes. Pretty much like that. But I'm interested in example 3 only and the expected output is '3'. And function will only get be executed inside the stack level 3. I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated**:

You could create a class to handle it.
I believe that this class will be enough to do it let me know if you need futher help.

```
class Ob {

    static protected $_level = 0;
    static protected $_data = array();

    static function start() {
        ob_flush();
        self::$_level++;        
        ob_start("Ob::store");
    }

    static function end() {        
        ob_end_flush();      
        self::$_level--;
    }

    static function length($level) {
        ob_flush();
        return strlen(self::$_data[$level]);
    }

    static function store() {
        if(self::$_level != 0)
        self::$_data[self::$_level] .= ob_get_contents();                
    }

    static function printData() {
        print_r(self::$_data);        
    }
}
```

example:

```
Ob::start();
echo '1';
Ob::start();
echo '2222';
Ob::start();
echo '2';
echo Ob::length(1);
echo Ob::length(2);
echo Ob::length(3);
Ob::end();
echo Ob::length(1);
echo Ob::length(2);
echo Ob::length(3);
Ob::end();
echo Ob::length(1);
echo Ob::length(2);
echo Ob::length(3);
Ob::end();

echo Ob::length(1);    
echo Ob::length(2);    
echo Ob::length(3);
Ob::printData();
```

Comment: Indeed, this is very clever, thanks for sharing. But I need to get length of still active stack, not ended one. Sorry for making it vague. I've edited the main question to illustrate what I need and when I need it.

Comment: Just add a ob_flush() on Ob::length and the callback will store it on the array... (the callback is called on flush, not on end).  it wont print, after all the ob will be on the go, but you will get the size of the buffer.

Comment: Nope, it won't work as it flushes the contents of current stack.

Comment: Ob::start();
    echo '1';
    Ob::start();
    echo '22';
    Ob::start();
    echo '333';
    $l = Ob::length(1);
    Ob::end();
    Ob::end();
    Ob::end();

    echo $l; // prints 0

Comment: Thanks for the effort, Danilo. However, I just checked and it did not work as expected.